# Explicit cursor and group by

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a `select` statement with a `group by` statement let's call it `<SGB>` (there are more elements in the `select`, but the error message refers only to the `group by`).
The following works without error:

```
<SGB>;
```

but when I use this statement with an explicit cursor as such:

```
DECLARE CURSOR MMM IS 
   SGB;
BEGIN
   FOR MCR in MMM
   LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('blah');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I get the error message `ORA-00979: not a GROUP expression`

I could not find it, but is there some limitation for GROUP BY  when in a cursor definition?

EDIT: here is a simplified `SGB`:

```
select 
    A, to_date(B, 'format') BDATE,
    C, D, E, F
from TB_001
pivot 
(
    MAX(VAL)
    for NAM
    in ('C' C, 'D' D, 'E' E, 'F' F)
)
group by
    A, to_date(B, 'format'), C, D, E, F
having
    to_date(B, 'format') = select( max(to_date(B, 'format')) from from TB_001 )
    and D=1
;
```

Another way to say it is that I have a vertical table of parameters, and parameters values for procedures, together with a date. I need to put it in a horizontal way and keep only a subset of the relevant procedures. I wanted to have a cursor so that I can in the loop exec the procedure with the relevant parameters, and potentially save an execution status in another table.

Comment: sorry you need to post a [mcve] with the exact SQL.  There is no limitation for a cursor like that.  It is something else going on, but can't help w/o all the details

Comment: thanks, this helps. I made an MRE and can confirm so. unfortunately making a more complex MRE is tricky, as the select statement has multiple clauses 
 like using pivot, having, etc., and not so straightforward data.

Comment: Then I guess I can I will work on the MRE, and eventually will find the root cause.

Comment: Steve, can you paste what your `SGB` is?

Comment: Actually, you just have a typo:  LOOP END; should be END LOOP;  Oracle gives terrible errors.

Comment: @LajosArpad I added something that is close to the select statement. while there are more elements and conditions it gives an idea of the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a nice solution, but I got around it by saving the select in a temporary table and making the cursor on the temporary table.

```
create table TEMP_T as SGB;

declare cursor MMM is 
   select * from TEMP_T;
begin
   for MCR in MMM
   loop
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('blah');
   end loop;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table TEMP_T';
end;
```